# How do you turn off custom errors for localhost not on server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis

**Question:** Can someone tell me how to "approve server variable REMOTE_ADDR" in IIS 8?

**Background:**

I have IIS 8 on a Windows 2012 server, but I do all my website development from my PC, which is not on that server. My asp.net is version 4.5.  In Visual Studio, the solution is a "website" and I publish my files by using "Build > Publish Website."

To handle custom errors I have this block in my Web.config file. The problem is that I get the same error pages everyone else does when I'm working on pages in Visual Studio viewing them from the localhost on my PC.  When I do that, I manually comment out this block and enable another where the custom errors mode is off, and then switch it back when I do another website refresh to the server. (This happens a lot when a website is still in a development phase.)

I changed the mode to "RemoteOnly." This highlights another problem with having to change the mode back and forth: you sometimes forget to switch it back. Case in point.

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error_Pages/Error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/Error_Pages/4xx.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error_Pages/Unauthorized.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error_Pages/4xx.aspx" />        
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error_Pages/4xx.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="410" redirect="~/Error_Pages/4xx.aspx" />        
</customErrors>
```

I was hoping there might be a better solution, such as a way to tell IIS that I need to have custom errors off automatically. I came across this page via another [Stackoverflow post](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/troubleshoot-asp-net-errors-remotely-while-appearing-local), but the article appears to be written for an earlier version of Windows Server and/or IIS.

According to the article, there are only three simple steps for solving my problem.  I already have step 1 done. I was unable to complete step 2 because I could not find any way to do that in IIS version 8.

1. Set RemoteOnly for customErrors
2. Have server administrator approve server variable REMOTE_ADDR
3. Create URL Rewrite rule

I did a Google search for clarification on #2, but it only led me back to the same article I posted.

To provide further clarification, on opening IIS on the server and following the instructions, I do not see "URL Rewrite section" as an icon. The same reason I was not able to apply step #2 in the article that I cited was because I did not see the necessary link or icon in IIS.

This is a screenshot of what I see in my IIS version 8.

[image: IIS Screenshot]

Comment: 4. Use XDT transform and place the `<customErrors>` node in your `web.Release.config`.

Comment: I don't see a web.release.config document in my solution. I'll do some research and see how to find that (or make it). Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url rewrite option is not installed on your server, [download and install the extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Read the referenced post carefully to execute step 2:

- Open the site in the IIS Manager
- Double-click on/open the "URL Rewrite section":
  [image]
- Click "View Server Variables":
  [image]
- Right-click the panel to open the context menu or use the action menu on the right to <kbd>Add</kbd> the variable:
  [image]

### Note:

As others are mentioning, there are more advanced solutions to debugging your application. The ones that come to mind are:

- [Application Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqlCc.png) / [New Relic](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/)
- More advanced logging in your code so you can monitor the Windows Eventlog
- [Elmah](http://newrelic.com/)
- [Intellitrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) will allow you to collect a log of the actions on the server and debug locally.

To easily manage differences between development and production config files, make use of a [Configuration Transformation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/). There are several tools that make that easier like [SlowCheetah](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I do not see "URL Rewrite section" or anything similar.

Comment: To make sure nothing is missed, I manually expanded all folders. I see only two config files: "Web.config" and "Web.Debug.config".

Comment: Sorry -- I responded to the wrong comment. To answer your comment, I made sure to expand the "sites" folder and even expanded my website. No matter what I clicked "URL Rewrite" did not appear.

Comment: I just added the screenshot at the bottom of the question and I verified in the server Programs and Features that "url rewriting" is not present in the list of programs and features.

Comment: I verified in Server Manager that the feature is not installed. I'll need to work with the Server Admin during business hours to get that installed.

Comment: It's not as bad as I was afraid it would be. Installed URL Rewrite and refreshed IIS. It's there now.

Comment: Yes. Installation of URL Rewrite did the trick. I was able to find URL Rewrite on IIS and follow the instructions to add REMOTE_ADDR as a server variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should test and fix your application locally before publishing, or create a fake (secured) website in your server and do some debugging. However, I recommend you to install [ELMAH](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) to log your errors and view them nicely in a secure page of your website. You can use Nuget, search for Elmah or Elmah.mvc package (if you use asp.net mvc ;) and install it... you can connect it to your SQL Server database, save the logs in memory and other formats. I wouldn't waste time configuring IIS or asking permission to administrators.

Also you can use web.config transformations to automate the publish process. There is a "web.Release.config" file that is used by IIS when you publish your app (or in Release mode). Here is a [good article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) from the asp.net official site.

Comment: While this is all valuable information, it doesn't really answer the question, nor does it provide a clear description of the actions to take in order to apply the suggested steps.